# Contents in a new page while creating PDF using xmlworker

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I am creating PDF using `Itext` and `xmlworker`. My problem is I want to create the contents in new pages. Below is my code.

```
File file = new File("D:/PDFFiles/Sathesh.pdf");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
Document doc=new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 70, 70);
PdfWriter pdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);
doc.open();
XMLWorkerHelper worker=XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
String firstString="<table><tr><td>First Page</td></tr></table>" ;
String secondString="<table><tr><td>Second Page</td></tr></table>" ; 
String final=firstString+secondString;
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(final.getBytes());
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, doc, is);
doc.close();
fos.close();
```

I want the `firstString` in first page and `secondString` in page. Waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse the Strings separately and add a call to newPage() in between.

Something like this:

```
...
String firstString="<table><tr><td>First Page</td></tr></table>" ;
String secondString="<table><tr><td>Second Page</td></tr></table>" ;
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(firstString.getBytes());
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, doc, is);
doc.newPage();
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(secondString.getBytes());
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, doc, is);
doc.close();
fos.close();
```

Comment: hi will this create one PDF with 2 pages?